# SQL enforce 1:1 relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding database modelling.

Let's assume I have a table users:

```
users
-------
id:int
name:text
```

And one user_emails:

```
user_emails
-----------
id:int
user_id:int
email:text
```

I add a foreign key constraint on `user_emails.user_id` such that it must match a valid entry in `users.id`.

However, this does not guarantee that each user will have an e-mail.

I know at an application level I can easily enforce this (Ie: By validating that an 'email' field in a form is populated, etc.) but I was wondering, at a database (sql) level is there a way of enforcing the completeness of data? (That is, in this case, that each user has an email?)

Thanks! :)

Comment: just add not null, but that you title says is different than your post says, you want to enforce, 1:1 relation or not null values?. If you want the first option, just forget user_emails table, and add that column in your primary table users, if you want the second one, just put not null column, or much better use both.

Comment: why not use trigger?

Comment: As suggest by @JuanRuizdeCastilla just add NOT NULL constraint on your email:text field.

Comment: a NOT NULL constraint isnt enough to guarantee that each user will have an e-mail, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn your fk around

```
users
-----
id:int
name:text
user_emails_id:int (NOT NULL)

user_emails
-----
id:int
email:text (NOT NULL)
```

this way you force to have a relation in the email-table and if you set the email value not null, then you force to have at least an entry in the column

Edit based on the comment:
To achieve multiple emails for a user, you have to add a n:m table

```
users
-----
id:int
name:text
user_emails_reference_id:int (NOT NULL referencing user_email_references)

user_email_references
-----
id:int
user_email_id:int (NOT NULL Referencing user_emails)
user_id:int (NOT NULL Referencing users)

user_emails
-----
id:int
email:text (NOT NULL)
```

Comment: so, first insert is user_emails and next is users foreigned by user_emails. This is should works

Comment: Thanks, expanding on this, is there any way I could allow multiple emails for a user?

Comment: if you allow mulitple emials for a user then it isnt a 1:1 relation anymore.... but you can add a n:m relation table to it to achieve this goal

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to allow users to have multiple emails, but just to guarantee that there is at least one.  You can come quite close with MySQL constraints by doing:

```
create table Users (
    UserId int not null primary key, . . .
    . . .
    PrimaryEmailId int not null,
    constraint fk_PrimaryEmailId foreign key (UserId, PrimaryEmailId) references UserEmails(UserId, UserEmailId)
);

create table UserEmails (
    UserEmailId int not null primary key,
    UserId int not null,
    . . .,
    unique (UserId, UserEmailId),
    constraint fk_UserEmails_UserId foreign key (UserId) references Users(UserId)
);
```

This guarantees:

- Every user has exactly one primary email.
- Every email has one user.
- The primary email has the same user as the one specified.

Note the use of the funky foreign key relationship.  It would be sufficient to reference `UserEmailId`.  However, that would not guarantee that the user is the same.

You might also want to add a unique constraint to the email itself, so different users cannot share a single email.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense :) The thing is by adding a PrimaryEmail field to the 'user' table I feel like I'm adding overhead. The system should be able to infer that an e-mail exists for a user by checking the email.person_id column... But maybe that is something that is best deferred to the application layer?