# Enforcing a one to zero or one relationship in SQL

Tags: sql

I found an example on stackoverflow of how to enforce a 1 to 1 relationship ([SQL enforce 1:1 relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953258/sql-enforce-11-relation)), but I would like to know how I can use this example in a one to zero or one relationship

```
create table Users (
    UserId int not null primary key, . . .
    . . .
    PrimaryEmailId int not null,
    constraint fk_PrimaryEmailId foreign key (UserId, PrimaryEmailId) references UserEmails(UserId, UserEmailId)
);

create table UserEmails (
    UserEmailId int not null primary key,
    UserId int not null,
    . . .,
    unique (UserId, UserEmailId),
    constraint fk_UserEmails_UserId foreign key (UserId) references Users(UserId)
);
```

I am not entirely sure how to do it. My guess is that I would just remove the not null constraint from the UserId field in the UserEmails table, but I am not sure. Can somebody please explain how to correctly do it, thanks you very much.

Comment: If you're talking about having no email addresses for a given `UserId`, that's just a question of not inserting a record in `UserEmails`. If that's not what you mean, please [edit] your question to better explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RandomStacker . . . Please explain more about the exact relationship you want.

Comment: Do you want records in your UserEmails that doesn't belong to a User? Do you want to have multiple emails for a User?

Answer (score 2):

You would just remove the `NOT NULL` constraint:

```
create table Emails (
    EmailId int not null primary key,
    . . .,
);

create table Users (
    UserId int not null primary key, . . .
    . . .
    PrimaryEmailId int,
    constraint fk_PrimaryEmailId foreign key (PrimaryEmailId) references UserEmails(UserEmailId),
    contraint unq_users_primaryemailid unique(primaryemailid)
);
```

You also do not want the `UserId` in `UserEmails`.  I don't see what purpose it serves.

So, the `PrimaryEmailId` has a foreign key constraint; it can be `NULL`, so that is 0/1.  The `unique` constraint guarantees that two users cannot have the same primary email.